# EF Migration - Unable to create an object of [DbContext]

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a project which I started but can not seem to create the initial migration. Might just be missing something really stupid.

My Project is layout out like this:

- MovieFinder.Core - Contains all the entities
- MovieFinder.Infrastructure - Contains the DBContext
- Moviefinder.Web - the front end application

This is my DBContext which is in the `MovieFinder.Infrastructure` project:

```
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion;
using MovieFinder.Core.Entities;

namespace MovieFinder.Infrastructure.Data;

public class MovieContext : DbContext
{
    public MovieContext(DbContextOptions<MovieContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    
    public DbSet<Director> Directors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Episode> Episodes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Name> Names { get; set; }
    public DbSet<NameProfession> NameProfessions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Principal> Principals { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Profession> Professions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Rating> Ratings { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Title> Titles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TitleGenre> TitleGenres { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TitleName> TitleNames { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Writer> Writers { get; set; }
    
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            
        if (Database.ProviderName == "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite")
            foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
            {
                var properties = entityType.ClrType.GetProperties()
                    .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(decimal));
                var dateTimeProperties = entityType.ClrType.GetProperties()
                    .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(DateTimeOffset));
                foreach (var property in properties)
                    modelBuilder.Entity(entityType.Name).Property(property.Name)
                        .HasConversion<double>();
                foreach (var property in dateTimeProperties)
                    modelBuilder.Entity(entityType.Name).Property(property.Name)
                        .HasConversion(new DateTimeOffsetToBinaryConverter());
            }
    }
}
```

I have added the AddDbContext to the ConfigureService method in the Startup.cs in the `MovieFinder.Web` project.

```
services.AddDbContext<MovieContext>(opt =>
        {
            opt.UseSqlite(_config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                x => x.MigrationsAssembly("MovieFinder.Infrastructure"));
        });
```

The Connectionstring is stored in the appsettings.development.json file:

```
{
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data source=MovieFinder.db"
  }
}
```

So unless I have missed something, I believe I have everything set up. When I run the command `dotnet ef migrations add InitialDb -o Data/Migrations --startup-project MovieFinder.Web --project MovieFinder.Infrastructure` I get the following error.

```
Unable to create an object of type 'MovieContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
```

Another really helpful Microsoft message. lol

Comment: Did you follow the link in the error message?

Comment: @DavidG Yea, but like all Microsoft pages, not that helpful

Comment: Then you need to read harder, it literally tells you what to do.

Comment: Please indicate exactly what because from what I can tell I have everything setup as they say

Comment: Is it installed `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` ?

Comment: @OkanKaradag Yes it is

Comment: So I deleted the MovieFinder.Web project and started again, did everything exactly the same as before, and now it's working.....